# Simple ternary operation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to make a div change position on click and then revert to it's original position when clicked again. I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is.

```
$("#bottom").click(function() {

  var $about = $('#bottom'),
  top = $about.css('top') === '50%' ? '90%' : '50%';

$about.stop().animate({top: top}, 500);  
});
```

my css is:

```
#bottom {
top: 90%;
left: 0; right: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```

When I click #bottom, the div positions itself at 50%, but when I hit it again, nothing happens.

Comment: what does the console say? ternary looks fine from a syntax perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.css('top')` doesn't give you the literal CSS `top` declaration; it gives you the *calculated pixel amount* of the top. If your container for `#bottom` is 100px tall, then `$('#bottom').css('top')` will give you `90px`, *not* `90%`.

[Here's a fiddle with a solution for you.](https://jsfiddle.net/42z0uvu1/3/)

Comment: That definitely explains that, thank you. I solved the issue by using 50vh instead of 50%.

Comment: No problem - check my edit for a solution that works with percents.